# Latex: Epigraph environment without line

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have an epigraph definition that looks as follows:

```
\epigraph{This work has appeared in:}{Max Mustermann, How the Euro will crash.}
```

That looks then as follows

```
    This work has appeared in:
    -----------------------------
    Max Mustermann, How the Euro will crash.
```

It does look okay, but I do not like the line in between. Is there an easy way to get rid
of this one?

Comment: You can find an entire community on the [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), where no TeX-related question is too small.  They will probably want to know where this `\epigraph` is defined, though.  What class are you using?  Once the original definition is found it should not be too hard to patch.

Answer (score 5):

`\epigraphrule` controls the line after the quote and source if you are using the epigraph package.

Place the following command in the preamble.

```
\renewcommand{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
```